# Convert string resource path to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of resources (images) on my app all referenced as this into a resource dictionary

```
/MySolution.Images;component/Resources/MyImage.png
```

Now I need to convert some ones into a **ImageSource**

I tryed:

```
var img = new Uri(tb.ImageSource); // Throw error. 
myImg.Source = new BitmapImage(img);
```

How Can I do to convert  **/MySolution.Images;component/Resources/MyImage.png** into an Image Source ?

Comment: @TheGeneral is a WPF app

Comment: What is the `tb` element? What's his type?

Comment: @EldHasp tb is a CustomControl and ImageSource is a string that contains something like this: **/MySolution.Images;component/Resources/MyImage.png**

Answer (score 0):

> tb is a CustomControl and ImageSource is a string that contains something like this: /MySolution.Images;component/Resources/MyImage.png

If this is a string and an error occurs when creating the Uri, then the only reason is that the string contains an invalid value.
Unfortunately, without the source code of your Solution, it is impossible to tell what the correct content of this line should be.

I can only suggest ways to find the correct value.
In the project where `myImg` is located, try setting a test Image in XAML.
In the same XAML, in the Property Browser, go to the Source property and find the image you want.
Then run the application for execution.
Open the Dynamic Property Browser and view the value of this property.
If the picture is displayed, the correct value will be there.
Copy it to your keyboard clipboard (Ctrl + C) and paste it into your code.

If the image is in another assembly and you cannot bind the Source property to it in the Window.
Then create Image in the assembly where this image is located.
And in the main Window display this Image.
Further - according to the above.

And a recommendation not directly related to the problem, but improving the code.
The `tb.ImageSource` property is for storing an image.
By giving it the string type, you are only confusing yourself.
Change its type to ImageSource or BitmapImage.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my full resource uri, must include **pack://application:,,,** if resource is an embedded resource.

In my sample somethhing like this

**pack://application:,,,/MySolution.Images;component/Resources/MyImage.png**

Finally I transformed my resources like this:

```
string baseUri = !tb.ImageSource.StartsWith(@"pack://application:,,,")
    ? @"pack://application:,,," + tb.ImageSource
    : tb.ImageSource;
Uri img = new Uri(baseUri);
tb.ImageSource2 = new BitmapImage(img);
```